# Openshift: trigger pods restart sequentially

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

My application loads data during startup. So I need to restart application to change data.

Data is loaded from Oracle schema and can be changed by other application.

If the data is changed, application becomes partially functional and needs to be restarted.

**Requirement**: restart should be done automatically without downtime (old pod should be killed, when new one pass readiness check).

How this requirement can be fulfilled?

**Notes**:

1. I would really like to use liveness probe to check some URL with health check. **Issue**: AFAIK liveness probe kills pod as soon as check fails. So all
   pods will be killed simultaneously, which leads to a downtime
   during startup.
2. The desired behavior can be reached by a rolling deployment. However I don't want to perform it manually.
3. I don't want to implement loading data during pod operation for simplicity: it can load data only during startup. If pod state is not fully functional, it is killed and recreated.

Answer (score 0):

2 ways i can think of :
- Use statefulsets, the pods will be restarted in order and killed in reverse order.
- You can use deployment's spec.strategy.type = RollingUpgrade and pair it with maxUnavailable to greater than 1.

.spec.strategy.rollingUpdate.maxUnavailable

Comment: Hello @baltazar-chua: Thank you for the reply. Could you please give some details? What will trigger restart?

Comment: I dont know your exact use case.  There might be a better way to tackle this. Nevertheless, do you think pairing livenessprobe with statefulsets will give you the desired result?  For example since you are using statefulsets you can make them react to liveness in the order of the statefulset i.e. 1,2,3...